# How can I add the v-mask library to vue3 application?

Tags: vuejs3

I am trying to add masks to input fields and following the below link.

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-use-v-mask-when-building-forms-with-vue-js-62b774d4b927

The installation for "v-mask" library was successful but I am getting the below error when I launch the application.

```
Uncaught TypeError: e.filter is not a function
at L_ (v-mask.esm.js:516:7)
at Object.use (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4385:21)
at main.js:22:5
at main.js:24:17
```

Below is the code from main.js

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import VueMask from 'v-mask';

const app = createApp(App);

app.use(VueMask);

app.mount("#app");
```

Comment: It's not compatible with Vue 3.  ["This version requires Vue 2.X"](https://github.com/probil/v-mask#cd-installation).

Comment: Thank you. Is there any suggested package for Vue3 ?

Answer (score 0):

The link you mentioned is for `Vue 2`, for `Vue 3` use this [vue-imask](https://github.com/uNmAnNeR/imaskjs/tree/master/packages/vue-imask) instructions.

After installation is done:

```
npm i vue-imask
```

Go to your project `main.js` file and import `IMaskDirective` from `vue-imask` and add it as `directive` to your `app` object before `mount` e.g.

```js
import { IMaskDirective } from 'vue-imask';

app.directive('imask', IMaskDirective);
app.mount("#app");
```

Now in your project component/view files you can use `v-imask` directive as following:

```js
<input v-imask="{mask: <mask-properties>}" @accept="method()" />
```